# Transition rollback only partially

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

When I execute this code, an order object remains in the DB at the end, in which the label is test. So the changing of the object is rolled back, but not the creation. My expectation is that the DB contains no order or chat channel entry after the call

```
@Autowired
private OrderRepository orderRepository;

@Autowired
private ChatChannelRepository chatChannelRepository;

@RequestMapping(value = "/order/price", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
@Transactional
public double calculatePrice() throws CustomException {

    Order order = new Order();
    order.setLabel("Test");

    orderRepository.save(order);

    ChatChannel channel = new ChatChannel();
    channel.setOrder(order);

    chatChannelRepository.save(channel);

    order.setLabel("Test2");

    orderRepository.save(order);


    throw new RuntimeException("Test");
}



   @Transactional
 public interface ChatChannelRepository extends 
CrudRepository<ChatChannel, Long> {

public ChatChannel findById(long id);
}



@Transactional
public interface OrderRepository extends CrudRepository<Order, Long> 
{
public Order findById(long id);

public List<Order> findByBudgetIn(List<Budget> budgets);

public List<Order> findByBudgetInAndCurrentChainPosPhaseEquals(List<Budget> budgets, Phase phase);

public List<Order> findByProcessors(User currentUser);

}
```

Comment: can you share your repository?

Comment: The transactions follow the [**ACID**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) principles. The `A` stands for the `atomicity` which guarantees preventing updates to the database occurring only partially. Do you have an use-case that really needs to violate this principle? The solution is to break the transactions into more ones.

Comment: Please add the Code for CustomException

Comment: `public class CustomException extends RuntimeException {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4328801700970393470L;

    public CustomException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    public CustomException(ErrorCodes errorCode) {
        super(String.valueOf(errorCode));
    }

    public CustomException(Exception e) {
        super(e);
    }
}`

Comment: Wild guess the DB you use is MySQL? Also making your web layer the transactional boundary is not the best of ideas, move that code to a service and make that transactional. Your web layer should merely be a small/thin integration layer from the web to your internal structures.

Comment: Either `calculatePrice` is not transactional (as in spring does not create transaction for that method) or save methods on repositories create their own autonomous transactions. To find this out show the stacktrace of error. Also share the relevant part of spring config.